# Quoting in the function arguments error

Tags: bash, quoting

How should be fixed `command` variable to get a correct behavior?

```
#!/bin/bash

function f ( )
{
    echo "$2"
}
command="f --option=\"One Two Three\" --another_option=\"Four Five Six\""
$command

f --option="One Two Three" --another_option="Four Five Six"
```

First calling is wrong, second - right

```
$> ./test.sh 
Two
--another_option=Four Five Six
```

Comment: also appears in [unix/linux stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20349/4667)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BASH FAQ entry #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

TL;DR: Use an array.

```
command=(f --option="One Two Three" --another_option="Four Five Six")
"${command[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fix the variable. But you can:

```
eval $command
```